# Jquery Autocomplete - autosuggest plugin problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I using this plugin http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin
While typing "MAS" there is no data matched, so its displaying "NO data found", but at the same time
if i press tab key "MAS" with delete symbol appearing in my text field..

any solution for this

Comment: Sorry but we can't help you without any futher informations about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular plugin supports "tabbing" to use multiple user selection choices.

If you are looking for plain auto-complete plugin.
try

a) Use a different plugin - google it, tons of them, also here's a link to an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery

b) Remove the tab key handler from that plugin. Download the plugin and remove the tab handler.
or as the documentation says http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin; try writing your own event handlers for

`selectionAdded`: callback function - Custom function that is run when a selection is made by choosing one from the Results dropdown, or by using the tab/comma keys to add one. The selection item is passed into this callback function as 'elem'.
Example: selectionAdded: function(elem){ elem.fadeTo("slow", 0.33); }

`selectionRemoved`: callback function - Custom function that is run when a selection removed from the AutoSuggest by using the delete key or by clicking the "x" inside the selection. The selection item is passed into this callback function as 'elem'.
Example: selectionRemoved: function(elem){ elem.fadeTo("fast", 0, function(){ elem.remove(); }); }